# Batch file to get total file qty and sum total file size by specific month

Tags: date, cmd

I have a number of various folders on a windows 2016 server.
I also have a template of files to process for each folder.
With the 2 above conditions I would like a report output detailing total number of files and their total size by specific month.

example of one folder: c:\temp1 folder, template to use p*.log. month- Jan 2023.
folder contains:

t1.log 17-Jan-23 5 kb

p1.log 17-jan-23 10 kb

p3.log 17-mar-23 15 kb

p2.log 18-jan-23 20 kb

And I want the output to be:

c:\temp1 - Jan 2023 - 2 files - total 30 kb

NOTE: Another example of a folder, could be c:\temp2, template to use r*.pgp - Jan 2023.

Not tried anything, not really a DOS batch expert.

Comment: DOS Batch files can't really do aggregation - can you use PowerShell instead?

Comment: Any guidance around using powershell also welcome!